# The limit of $x((1+{1 \over x})^x -e)$ As $x$ goes to infinity

Tags: calculus

### $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}x((1+{1 \over x})^x -e)$

I tried this by L'Hospital's rule. Here the $\log$ is a natural logarithm.

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {{(1+{1 \over x})^x -e} \over {1 \over x}} =  \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+ \frac{1}{x})\bullet(1+ \frac{1}{x})^x \bullet (1+ \frac{1}{x})'}{(\frac{1}{x})'}$
by L'Hospital (Differentiate by $x$)

Since the $(\frac{1}{x})' = (1+ \frac{1}{x})'$, only left to do is just calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \log(1+\frac{1}{x})\bullet(1+\frac{1}{x})^x = 0
$

But the according to wolfram alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x%28%281%2B1%2Fx%29%5E+x-e%29+as+x-%3Einfinity, The answer was $- \frac{e}{2}$

What did I wrong in my solution?

Comment: If the $a$ in $a^x$ is a function involving $x$, then $\dfrac{d}{dx}a^x=a^x \ln a$ is not true.

Comment: You made a mistake calculating the derivative of $x\log(1+\frac{1}{x})$ $-$ you multiplied istead of adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you differentiate $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x-e$,what you get is$$\frac{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x \left((x+1)\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)-1\right)}{x+1}.$$So, you should compute the limit$$\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{x^2\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\left((x+1)\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)-1\right)}{x+1},$$which is $-\frac e2$ indeed.